# Unable to play DVDs Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dvd

After installing recommended libraries I am still unable to play any DVD. I am able to play CDs just fine but when I insert a DVD, I get this error: "Unable to mount (DVD NAME) Error creating moint point: No such file or directory."
If I manually mount my cdrom with `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /cdrom` I can access the VIDEO_TS file but am still unable to actually play the DVD itself.

sudo lshw output:

```
     *-scsi:2
      physical id: 3
      logical name: scsi2
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVDRAM GH24NS90
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: IN01
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the fix. I was missing /media/cdrom. I am not sure why it was never created in the first place but it is working now :D

Comment: I recommend accepting your own answer (since it's what solved the problem) by clicking the green check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up to decode the copy protection on DVD's in order to play them....

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: I have already done this with the same result. Still gives me the same error saying the mount point does not exist.